# Arduino Remote controlled RGB LED strip, having issues with brightness/dimming

Tags: programming, led

I have this sketch:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <RGBMood.h>

int RECV_PIN = 2;  // IR-Receiver PIN
int led = 13;       // Satus-LED PIN
int modus;          // Modus for Interrupt-Querry 
int ledr = 11;       // RGB LED red PIN
int ledg = 12;       // RGB LED green PIN                       
int ledb = 13;       // RGB LED blue PIN
int SerialBuffer = 0; 

RGBMood m(ledr, ledg, ledb);

int timerwert = 20;   // Timer time for Interrupt in ms

String readString;

// Color arrays
int black[3]  = { 0, 0, 0 };
int white[3]  = { 100, 100, 100 };
int red[3]    = { 100, 0, 0 };
int green[3]  = { 0, 100, 0 };
int blue[3]   = { 0, 0, 100 };
int yellow[3] = { 40, 95, 0 };
int dimWhite[3] = { 30, 30, 30 };

int brightness = 0;    // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount = 5;    // how many points to fade the LED by
// etc.

// Set initial color
int redVal = black[0];
int grnVal = black[1]; 
int bluVal = black[2];

int wait = 10;      // 10ms internal crossFade delay; increase for slower fades
int hold = 0;       // Optional hold when a color is complete, before the next crossFade
int DEBUG = 1;      // DEBUG counter; if set to 1, will write values back via serial
int loopCount = 60; // How often should DEBUG report?
int repeat = 3;     // How many times should we loop before stopping? (0 for no stop)
int j = 0;          // Loop counter for repeat

// Initialize color variables
int prevR = redVal;
int prevG = grnVal;
int prevB = bluVal;

#define ON                0xF4F37A66
#define OFF               0x1363ADB4
#define BRIGHTNESS_UP     0xE6721691
#define BRIGHTNESS_DOWN   0xE9721B48
#define FLASH             0xFFF00F
#define STROBE            0xFFE817
#define FADE              0x39ED1255
#define SMOOTH            0xFFC837

#define RED               0x9D561314
#define GREEN             0XCB8E93A5
#define BLUE              0xC88E8EEC
#define WHITE             0x16DBBEE3

#define ORANGE            0xFFB04F
#define YELLOW_DARK       0xFFA857
#define YELLOW_MEDIUM     0xFF9867
#define YELLOW_LIGHT      0xFF8877

#define GREEN_LIGHT       0XFF30CF
#define GREEN_BLUE1       0XFF28D7
#define GREEN_BLUE2       0XFF18E7
#define GREEN_BLUE3       0XFF08F7

#define BLUE_RED          0XFF708F
#define PURPLE_DARK       0XFF6897
#define PURPLE_LIGHT      0XFF58A7
#define PINK              0XFF48B7


IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledr, OUTPUT); // Set RGB LED Pins as Output
  pinMode(ledg, OUTPUT); // Set RGB LED Pins as Output
  pinMode(ledb, OUTPUT); // Set RGB LED Pins as Output
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); // set Status-LED as Output 
  m.setMode(RGBMood::RANDOM_HUE_MODE);  // Automatic random fade.
  m.setHoldingTime(4000);  // Keep the same color for 4 seconds before fading again.
  m.setFadingSteps(150);   // Fade with 150 steps.
  m.setFadingSpeed(50);    // Each step last 50ms. A complete fade takes 50*150 = 7.5 seconds
  m.setHSB(random(359), 255, 255);

Serial.begin(9600);

  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start of IR-Recive

  Timer1.initialize(timerwert); // Initialisation of Timer-Interrupts
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(leseIR); // IR-Read from Interrupt
}

void leseIR(){
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
     irrecv.resume();  // Receive the next value
    switch (results.value)  {

      case FADE: // Modus Fade (DIY 4)
        modus = 1;  
      break;

      case 0xFF906F: // Modus pcambi (DIY 5)
        modus = 2;  
      break;

      case ON:  //Power
       modus = 0;
        crossFade(white);         // RGB LEDs Off 
      break;
            case OFF:  //Power
       modus = 0;
        crossFade(black);         // RGB LEDs Off 
      break;

      case BLUE:  //Blau 0,0,255
        modus = 0;
      crossFade(blue);
      break;

      case RED: //Rot
        modus = 0;
        crossFade(red);
      break;

      case GREEN://Grün
        modus = 0;
        crossFade(green);
      break;  

      case WHITE: //Weiss
        modus = 0;
        crossFade(white);
      break;

      case BRIGHTNESS_UP: //DIMMING
        modus = 0;
        // fade in from min to max in increments of 5 points:
  for(int fadeValue = 0 ; fadeValue <= 255; fadeValue +=5) { 
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledg, fadeValue);    

  }

      break;

       case BRIGHTNESS_DOWN: //orange
        modus = 0;
      for(int fadeValue = 255 ; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -=5) { 
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledg, fadeValue);    
      }

      break;

      case 0xFFAA55://Grün mitrtel
        modus = 0;

      break;  

      case 0xFF926D: //blau mittel
        modus = 0;

      break; 

      case 0xFF12ED: //rosa
        modus = 0;

      break;      


     }             // Switch END

  }               

}                  

void loop() {
if(modus==1){    // Querry pb Modus:1 
m.tick();
}

      Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
      Serial.println(DEC);
      Serial.println(DEC);
      Serial.println(DEC);

  } 


  int calculateStep(int prevValue, int endValue) {
  int step = endValue - prevValue; // What's the overall gap?
  if (step) {                      // If its non-zero, 
    step = 1020/step;              //   divide by 1020
  } 
  return step;
}

/* The next function is calculateVal. When the loop value, i,
*  reaches the step size appropriate for one of the
*  colors, it increases or decreases the value of that color by 1. 
*  (R, G, and B are each calculated separately.)
*/

int calculateVal(int step, int val, int i) {

  if ((step) && i % step == 0) { // If step is non-zero and its time to change a value,
    if (step > 0) {              //   increment the value if step is positive...
      val += 1;           
    } 
    else if (step < 0) {         //   ...or decrement it if step is negative
      val -= 1;
    } 
  }
  // Defensive driving: make sure val stays in the range 0-255
  if (val > 255) {
    val = 255;
  } 
  else if (val < 0) {
    val = 0;
  }
  return val;
}

/* crossFade() converts the percentage colors to a 
*  0-255 range, then loops 1020 times, checking to see if  
*  the value needs to be updated each time, then writing
*  the color values to the correct pins.
*/

void crossFade(int color[3]) {
  // Convert to 0-255
  int R = (color[0] * 255) / 100;
  int G = (color[1] * 255) / 100;
  int B = (color[2] * 255) / 100;

  int stepR = calculateStep(prevR, R);
  int stepG = calculateStep(prevG, G); 
  int stepB = calculateStep(prevB, B);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 1020; i++) {
    redVal = calculateVal(stepR, redVal, i);
    grnVal = calculateVal(stepG, grnVal, i);
    bluVal = calculateVal(stepB, bluVal, i);

    analogWrite(ledr, redVal);   // Write current values to LED pins
    analogWrite(ledg, grnVal);      
    analogWrite(ledb, bluVal); 

    delay(wait); // Pause for 'wait' milliseconds before resuming the loop


  }
  // Update current values for next loop
  prevR = redVal; 
  prevG = grnVal; 
  prevB = bluVal;
  delay(hold); // Pause for optional 'wait' milliseconds before resuming the loop
}
```

It's working like a charm, the fade operates smoothly using `timer1`, the colors appear correct on led, but I can't fix the brightness part. **Can  someone provide sample code to do this?**

If anyone else wants to use the code, I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560, please use the same PINs as mine since timers works only on 11,12,13 on this Arduino. ([link with pin info regarding several Arduino boards](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_TimerOne.html))

- [RGB mood library](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,90160.0.html)
- [TimerOne library](http://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne)
- [IR Library](http://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote)

I'm using a small Xbox 360 IR control (no numbers keypad), some HEX codes are left intact from the original sketch found on internet.

[original topic](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=256671)

Comment: Whats wrong with the brightness part?

Comment: i cannot set the brightness of the leds. Maybe i should use the expression "dim" instead of brightness to make it more clear. If i set the color RED, i cannot dim it up or down, same aplies for GREEN and BLUE.

Comment: No 'brightness' was clear, I just couldn't tell what wasn't working from your question. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a delay in the fade loop, this goes from 0 to 255 almost instantly:

```
for(int fadeValue = 0 ; fadeValue <= 255; fadeValue +=5) { 
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(ledg, fadeValue);    
}
```

But I'm not sure you want to fade from off to on in one go. If you want to just increment and decrement the brightness:

First notice that `prevR, prevG, prevB` hold the current led values. So we shall use them.

Change the switch case to:

```
case BRIGHTNESS_UP:
    modus = 0;
    int c[3];
    // decrease by 0.9*value but also take off 2 so we get to zero
    c[0] = (prevR-2) * 90 / 100;
    c[1] = (prevG-2) * 90 / 100;
    c[2] = (prevB-2) * 90 / 100;
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        if (c[j] < 0) c[j] = 0;
    }
    crossFade(c);
    break;

case BRIGHTNESS_DOWN:
    modus = 0;
    int c[3];
    // increase value by 1/0.9 but also add 2 so we get off zero
    c[0] = (prevR+2) * 100 / 90 + 2;
    c[1] = (prevG+2) * 100 / 90 + 2;
    c[2] = (prevB+2) * 100 / 90 + 2;
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        if (c[j] > 100) c[j] = 100;
    }
    crossFade(c);
    break;
```

I can't check this to see if it works see please test and see.

**Edit**

Different approach:

Global variable for brightness:

```
int brightness = 100;
int c[3];
```

Change this value each time:

```
case BRIGHTNESS_UP:
    modus = 0;
    brightness += 5;
    if (brightness > 255) brightness = 255;
    c[0] = prevR; c[1] = prevG; c[2] = prevB;
    crossFade(c);
    break;

case BRIGHTNESS_DOWN:
    modus = 0;
    brightness -= 5;
    if (brightness < 0) brightness = 0;
    c[0] = prevR; c[1] = prevG; c[2] = prevB;
    crossFade(c);
    break;
```

Then in `crossFade` we change the last few lines:

```
analogWrite(ledr, redVal * brightness / 255);   // Write current values to LED pins
analogWrite(ledg, grnVal * brightness / 255);      
analogWrite(ledb, bluVal * brightness / 255);
```

**Edit 2:**

I think that what might be happening is that the color is reduced by brightness, then that reduced value is saved in prevR/G/B when actually it should just be the full brightness value. Try changing last bit of `crossFade` to :

```
prevR = color[0]; 
prevG = color[1]; 
prevB = color[2];
```

Comment: IDE reports that there is redeclaration of 'int c [3]

Comment: Try move `int c[3]` outside `leseIR()` and make it global. Delete all instances in the switch statement.

Comment: you might want to muck around with the ratios too, say use 80 instead of 90 and 5 instead of 2 etc. I tried to use a ratio because our eyes perceive brightness on a log scale, so a small change in low brightness is like a large change in high brightness.

Comment: i removed it, code compiled, but, when i press the brighntess up button the color fades to black (switches off) and when i press the brightness down then the color brights up to white after several button presses.

Comment: oops, i got `BRIGHTNESS_UP` and `BRIGHTNESS_DOWN` round the wrong way

Comment: see this question for some people's approach to getting brightness changes correct  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/correcting-for-non-linear-brightness-in-leds-when-using-pwm

Comment: The brightness might actually have to be made a separate variable and applied in crossFade

Comment: Hi, i've tried the edited approach, all colors dim to 0, with a single button press, no matter if press the up or down brightness. So, if i've chosen the `GREEN` color, it dims to 0, the same applies to all. Crossfade class do the following: When the selected color is `RED` and press the `GREEN` button, then `RED` dims down to `0` and `GREEN` dims up to `100`. So my guess is that we must not use the `Crossfade` class to control brightness.

Comment: Hey could you make `crossFade` print out the `colour` and the `R G B` values and just check they look ok? e.g. `Serial.println(colour[0],DEC);` and so on.

Comment: `RED` button pressed results `crossfade` **:** `100,0,0` and `color` **:** `255,0,0` .  GREEN `crossfade` **:** `0,100,0` and `color` **:** `0,255,0` **.** BLUE `crossfade` **:** `0,0,100` and `color` **:** `0,0,255` **.** WHITE `crossfade` **:** `100,100,100` and color `255,255,255` **.** So everything seems ok.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant for the brightness up / down with the code I posted. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've moved the `analogWrite` part of the code inside the `switch case` `BRIGHTNESS_UP` & `BRIGHTNESS_DOWN` and it's working. I also removed the `crossFade(c);` line.

Here's the working code:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <RGBMood.h>

int RECV_PIN = 2;  // IR-Receiver PIN
int led = 13;       // Satus-LED PIN
int modus;          // Modus for Interrupt-Querry 
int ledr = 11;       // RGB LED red PIN
int ledg = 12;       // RGB LED green PIN                       
int ledb = 13;       // RGB LED blue PIN
int SerialBuffer = 0; 
int c[3];


//RGB Pins Array
int CH[3] = {11, 12, 13};
int val[3] = {0, 0, 0}; // led brightness 0-255


RGBMood m(ledr, ledg, ledb);

int timerwert = 20;   // Timer time for Interrupt in ms

String readString;

// Color arrays
int black[3]  = { 0, 0, 0 };
int white[3]  = { 100, 100, 100 };
int red[3]    = { 100, 0, 0 };
int green[3]  = { 0, 100, 0 };
int blue[3]   = { 0, 0, 100 };
int yellow[3] = { 40, 95, 0 };
int dimWhite[3] = { 30, 30, 30 };

int brightness = 100;    // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount = 5;    // how many points to fade the LED by
// etc.

// Set initial color
int redVal = black[0];
int grnVal = black[1]; 
int bluVal = black[2];

int wait = 10;      // 10ms internal crossFade delay; increase for slower fades
int hold = 0;       // Optional hold when a color is complete, before the next crossFade
int DEBUG = 1;      // DEBUG counter; if set to 1, will write values back via serial
int loopCount = 60; // How often should DEBUG report?
int repeat = 3;     // How many times should we loop before stopping? (0 for no stop)
int j = 0;          // Loop counter for repeat


// Initialize color variables
int prevR = redVal;
int prevG = grnVal;
int prevB = bluVal;

#define ON                0xF4F37A66
#define OFF               0x1363ADB4
#define BRIGHTNESS_UP     0xE6721691
#define BRIGHTNESS_DOWN   0xE9721B48
#define FLASH             0xFFF00F
#define STROBE            0xFFE817
#define FADE              0x39ED1255
#define SMOOTH            0xFFC837

#define RED               0x9D561314
#define GREEN             0XCB8E93A5
#define BLUE              0xC88E8EEC
#define WHITE             0x16DBBEE3

#define ORANGE            0xFFB04F
#define YELLOW_DARK       0xFFA857
#define YELLOW_MEDIUM     0xFF9867
#define YELLOW_LIGHT      0xFF8877

#define GREEN_LIGHT       0XFF30CF
#define GREEN_BLUE1       0XFF28D7
#define GREEN_BLUE2       0XFF18E7
#define GREEN_BLUE3       0XFF08F7

#define BLUE_RED          0XFF708F
#define PURPLE_DARK       0XFF6897
#define PURPLE_LIGHT      0XFF58A7
#define PINK              0XFF48B7
#define MAX 255 

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledr, OUTPUT); // Set RGB LED Pins as Output
  pinMode(ledg, OUTPUT); // Set RGB LED Pins as Output
  pinMode(ledb, OUTPUT); // Set RGB LED Pins as Output
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); // set Status-LED as Output 
 //initiate rgb pins output
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    pinMode(CH[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  m.setMode(RGBMood::RANDOM_HUE_MODE);  // Automatic random fade.
  m.setHoldingTime(4000);  // Keep the same color for 4 seconds before fading again.
  m.setFadingSteps(150);   // Fade with 150 steps.
  m.setFadingSpeed(50);    // Each step last 50ms. A complete fade takes 50*150 = 7.5 seconds
  m.setHSB(random(359), 255, 255);

Serial.begin(9600);

  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start of IR-Recive

  Timer1.initialize(timerwert); // Initialisation of Timer-Interrupts
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(leseIR); // IR-Read from Interrupt
}

void leseIR(){
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
     irrecv.resume();  // Receive the next value
    switch (results.value)  {

      case FADE: // Modus Fade (DIY 4)
        modus = 1;  
      break;

      case 0xFF906F: // Modus pcambi (DIY 5)
        modus = 2;  
      break;

      case ON:  //Power
       modus = 0;
        crossFade(white);         // RGB LEDs Off 
      break;
            case OFF:  //Power
       modus = 0;
        crossFade(black);         // RGB LEDs Off 
      break;

      case BLUE:  //Blau 0,0,255
        modus = 0;
      crossFade(blue);
      break;

      case RED: //Rot
        modus = 0;
        crossFade(red);
      break;

      case GREEN://Grün
        modus = 0;
        crossFade(green);
      break;  

      case WHITE: //Weiss
        modus = 0;
        crossFade(white);
      break;

      case BRIGHTNESS_UP: //DIMMING UP
        modus = 0;
    brightness += 5;
    if (brightness > 255) brightness = 255;
    c[0] = prevR; c[1] = prevG; c[2] = prevB;
    analogWrite(ledr, redVal * brightness / 255);   // Write current values to LED pins
    analogWrite(ledg, grnVal * brightness / 255);      
    analogWrite(ledb, bluVal * brightness / 255);

      break;

       case BRIGHTNESS_DOWN: //DIMMING DOWN
         modus = 0;
    brightness -= 5;
    if (brightness < 0) brightness = 0;
    c[0] = prevR; c[1] = prevG; c[2] = prevB;
    analogWrite(ledr, redVal * brightness / 255);   // Write current values to LED pins
    analogWrite(ledg, grnVal * brightness / 255);      
    analogWrite(ledb, bluVal * brightness / 255);


      break;

      case 0xFFAA55://Grün mitrtel
        modus = 0;
      break;  

      case 0xFF926D: //blau mittel
        modus = 0;

      break; 

      case 0xFF12ED: //rosa
        modus = 0;

      break;      


     }             // Switch END

  }               
}                  

void loop() {
if(modus==1){    // Querry pb Modus:1 
m.tick();
}
if(modus==2){    // Querry pb Modus:1 

}
        Serial.println(prevR);
        Serial.println(prevG);
        Serial.println(prevB);
//      Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
//      Serial.println(DEC);
//      Serial.println(DEC);
//      Serial.println(DEC);
//      Serial.print("channel 1,2,3 values:");              // sends  brightness values to the serial monitor
    //  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){                             // every time the remote is pressed
    //  Serial.print(CH[i]);
//      Serial.print("   ");
    // } 
  } 


  int calculateStep(int prevValue, int endValue) {
  int step = endValue - prevValue; // What's the overall gap?
  if (step) {                      // If its non-zero, 
    step = 1020/step;              //   divide by 1020
  } 
  return step;
}

/* The next function is calculateVal. When the loop value, i,
*  reaches the step size appropriate for one of the
*  colors, it increases or decreases the value of that color by 1. 
*  (R, G, and B are each calculated separately.)
*/

int calculateVal(int step, int val, int i) {

  if ((step) && i % step == 0) { // If step is non-zero and its time to change a value,
    if (step > 0) {              //   increment the value if step is positive...
      val += 1;           
    } 
    else if (step < 0) {         //   ...or decrement it if step is negative
      val -= 1;
    } 
  }
  // Defensive driving: make sure val stays in the range 0-255
  if (val > 255) {
    val = 255;
  } 
  else if (val < 0) {
    val = 0;
  }
  return val;
}

/* crossFade() converts the percentage colors to a 
*  0-255 range, then loops 1020 times, checking to see if  
*  the value needs to be updated each time, then writing
*  the color values to the correct pins.
*/

void crossFade(int color[3]) {
  // Convert to 0-255
  int R = (color[0] * 255) / 100;
  int G = (color[1] * 255) / 100;
  int B = (color[2] * 255) / 100;

  int stepR = calculateStep(prevR, R);
  int stepG = calculateStep(prevG, G); 
  int stepB = calculateStep(prevB, B);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 1020; i++) {
    redVal = calculateVal(stepR, redVal, i);
    grnVal = calculateVal(stepG, grnVal, i);
    bluVal = calculateVal(stepB, bluVal, i);

    analogWrite(ledr, redVal);   // Write current values to LED pins
    analogWrite(ledg, grnVal);      
    analogWrite(ledb, bluVal); 

    delay(wait); // Pause for 'wait' milliseconds before resuming the loop


  }
  // Update current values for next loop
  prevR = redVal; 
  prevG = grnVal; 
  prevB = bluVal;
  delay(hold); // Pause for optional 'wait' milliseconds before resuming the loop
}
```

thanks geometrikal for your support! You believe it's possible to manipulate the dimming of the fade effect too? It's using the RGBMood class to create a HSB color mix.